# Reference on editor from xtype component

Tags: extjs

How to get reference on editor from components class, which i use as xtype in editor's config.

columns: [{
  editor: {
    xtype: 'myComponent'
  }
}]

I can get reference with this.ownerCt, but is there any better way?

Comment: Trying to access the editor from the component sounds like a bad idea, because the component could also be used outside editor. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I found another solution. I am bubbling change event from component to grid, and i have editors reference there. Thanks anyway.